# Rhai: Scope only accessible for directly called function?

Tags: rust, scripting, scope, rhai

My rhai script has two functions, `direct` and `indirect` and I'd like to supply variables using a `Scope`. (I.e. I'd *not* like to pass them as arguments to the functions.) When I call `direct` with a scope, the script apparently is able to access the variable from the scope.

However, when I call `indirect` (which delegates work to `direct`), execution errs out because it cannot find the variables in the `Scope`.

[This program](https://www.rustexplorer.com/b#%2F*%0A%5Bdependencies%5D%0Arhai%20%3D%20%22*%22%0A*%2F%0A%0Ause%20rhai%3A%3A%7BEngine%2C%20Scope%7D%3B%20%0A%20%0A%23%5Ballow(unused_must_use)%5D%20%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20let%20engine%20%3D%20Engine%3A%3Anew()%3B%20%0A%20%20%20%20let%20ast%20%3D%20engine.compile(r%22%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fn%20direct()%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20print(x)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%3C-----%20Note%3A%20This%20uses%20x%2C%20which%20is%20assumed%20to%20be%20supplied%20by%20Scope%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fn%20indirect()%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20direct()%3B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%0A%20%20%20%20%22).unwrap()%3B%20%0A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20I%20understand%20this%20(x%20not%20in%20scope)%20%0A%20%20%20%20engine.call_fn%3A%3A%3C()%3E(%26mut%20Scope%3A%3Anew()%2C%20%26ast%2C%20%22direct%22%2C%20())%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.expect_err(%22Because%20of%20missing%20%27x%27%22)%3B%20%0A%20%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20scope%20%3D%20Scope%3A%3Anew()%3B%20%0A%20%20%20%20scope.push(%22x%22%2C%201)%3B%20%0A%20%0A%20%20%20%20engine.call_fn%3A%3A%3C()%3E(%26mut%20scope%2C%20%26ast%2C%20%22direct%22%2C%20())%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.expect(%22Works%20as%20expected%20as%20%27x%27%20is%20supplied%20by%20scope.%22)%3B%20%0A%20%0A%20%20%20%20engine.call_fn%3A%3A%3C()%3E(%26mut%20scope%2C%20%26ast%2C%20%22indirect%22%2C%20())%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.expect_err(%22This%20returns%20Err%20although%20%27x%27%20is%20supplied%20by%20scope%20-%20why%3F%22)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%3C---%20Can%20I%20make%20this%20call%20work%3F%0A%7D) showcases my problem. (Note the last call to `expect_err` that shows that `indirect` cannot access `x` from the `scope`.)

```
use rhai::{Engine, Scope}; 
 
#[allow(unused_must_use)] 
fn main() { 
    let engine = Engine::new(); 
    let ast = engine.compile(r" 
        fn direct() { 
            print(x); // <----- Note: This uses x, which is assumed to be supplied by Scope 
        } 
        fn indirect() { 
            direct(); 
        } 
    ").unwrap(); 
 
    // I understand this (x not in scope) 
    engine.call_fn::<()>(&mut Scope::new(), &ast, "direct", ()) 
        .expect_err("Because of missing 'x'"); 
 
    let mut scope = Scope::new(); 
    scope.push("x", 1); 
 
    engine.call_fn::<()>(&mut scope, &ast, "direct", ()) 
        .expect("Works as expected as 'x' is supplied by scope."); 
 
    engine.call_fn::<()>(&mut scope, &ast, "indirect", ()) 
        .expect_err("This returns Err although 'x' is supplied by scope - why?"); // <--- Can I make this call work?
}
```

From [here](https://rhai.rs/book/engine/var.html) and [here](https://rhai.rs/book/engine/strict-var.html) I would have expected that even calling `indirect` would allow the callee `direct` to access variables from `scope`. Is my interpretation wrong here?

Or, alternatively: Is there a way that would allow me to successfully call `indirect`, supplying the value `x` in a `Scope`?

Comment: Never heard of Rhai, but according to a quick look at the documentation, these simply appear to be the semantics of the language. The scope you pass in is assigned to the function you call, but [it's not passed on to nested calls unless you use a special syntax](https://rhai.rs/book/language/fn-parent-scope.html). I can't tell you any more since I've never used the language. :)

Comment: @SvenMarnach Thank you. I did not expect this to be an "advanced topic". If you want to add an answer, I'll happily accept it.

Comment: I don't really know what I'm talking about, and I don't feel qualified to answer. I just spent 30 seconds googling and happened to hit that page – I didn't even notice it's under "advanced topics".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Rhai Book you can [Call a Function Within the Caller’s Scope](https://rhai.rs/book/language/fn-parent-scope.html):

> Rhai functions are pure, meaning that they depend on on their arguments and have no access to the calling environment.
>
> When a function accesses a variable that is not defined within that function’s Scope, it raises an evaluation error.
>
> It is possible, through a special syntax, to actually run the function call within the Scope of the parent caller – i.e. the Scope that makes the function call – and access/mutate variables defined there.
>
> ```
> fn foo(y) {            // function accesses 'x' and 'y', but 'x' is not defined
>     x += y;            // 'x' is modified in this function
>     let z = 0;         // 'z' is defined in this function's scope
>     x
> }
>
> let x = 1;             // 'x' is defined here in the parent scope
> foo(41);               // error: variable 'x' not found
>
> // Calling a function with a '!' causes it to run within the caller's scope
> foo!(41) == 42;        // the function can access and mutate the value of 'x'!
> x == 42;               // 'x' is changed!
> ```

So you should be able to accomplish this with `direct!()`.